# Preg_match find word after a word and after another word

Tags: php, preg-match

Im trying to get an array of words in a string using preg_match..`WORD1` and `WORD2` are variables which can change.

```
$content= 'class="gametitle WORD1">< ggg class="userid">WORD2 </ gg>';
```

i want to get `WORD1` and `WORD2`

right now Im only able to get word 1

```
$prematch=preg_match('/.class="gametitle.(.*)".*/isU', $content, $matches);

echo $matches[1];
```

thx in advance!

Comment: Please fix your problem description above: `"class="gametitle WORD1"> WORD2 "` certainly is not a valid string definition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (preg_match_all('/class\s?=\s?"gametitle\s+(\w+)"><[^>]+>\s?(\w+)/', $text, $matches)){
    $word1 = $matches[1][0];
    $word2 = $matches[2][0];
}
```

Or with `preg_match`:

```
if (preg_match('/class\s?=\s?"gametitle\s+(\w+)"><[^>]+>\s?(\w+)/', $text, $matches)){
    $word1 = $matches[1];
    $word2 = $matches[2];
}
```

Comment: thx but its not working..its not getting anyword..im going to try to explain it clearly...i want to get the word after class="gametitle and after class="userid

Comment: OK. In your original question, you didn't have that.

Comment: yeah sorry I didnt know it was going to remove the tag